# Trying to get ids of child views under a table row

Tags: java, android, view

I am developing an app which has long forms so its kind of difficult to manually do findViewById for each screen.
I have following structure in the screen where I am stuck.

```
Relative layout
->TableLayout
-->TableRow
--->And then each table row has 3 edittext in its own columns.
```

I am doing this

```
           TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.screen8_table1);
           int rowCount = table.getChildCount();

           TableRow rows = (TableRow)table.getChildAt(0);
           int viewCount = rows.getChildCount();
           EditText thisView = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
           View theView = rows.getChildAt(1);
           int Id = theView.getId();
           thisView.findViewById(Id);
           text = thisView.getText().toString();
           Log.i("View value",text);
```

When I try to get the ID is shows -1. 
Please help.

After the answer from Pavneet Singh I made this one change in the code

```
        FloatLabeledEditText et_one = (FloatLabeledEditText)rows.getChildAt(1);
        text = et_one.getEditText().getText().toString();
```

and now its working properly. Save me a tons of lines of code here!

Comment: I'm having trouble following here,  can you explain why are your trying to find a view by id with the id of the same view (`theView`'s `Id`)?  I Dont see how this approach may work for you. it would be helpful to see your layout file for `screen8_table1`.

Comment: There are 13 rows and each row has 3 edit text. I don't think I should do findViewById for each edit text. because there are 9 more such screens. I am looking for a way where I can write the code once and fetch from all fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `EditText` which is not a child of `TableRow`.

```
EditText thisView = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
View theView = rows.getChildAt(1);
int Id = theView.getId();
```

You can directly fetch it as

```
EditText eText_one = (EditText)rows.getChildAt(1);
// no need to use any id to fetch edittext reference
text = eText_one.getText().toString();
```

Update : you are using [customize editext](https://github.com/wrapp-archive/floatlabelededittext) so use

```
 com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText et_one =
                  (com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText)rows.ge‌​tChildAt(1);
```

Although this can be achieved with [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html) provided by design library

Comment: I tried this example. It has given me a fatal error saying java.lang.ClassCastException: com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Comment: seems like you are using some customize edittext so use `com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText et_one = (com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText)rows.getChildAt(1);`

Comment: Now i am getting the value as follows
View value: com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText{f62855b V.E..... ........ 300,0-398,81}
Shall I change anything in the xml file?

Comment: you should add your XML code although if you like then you can use inbuilt design lib's TextInputLayout to achieve the same behavior

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the FloatLabeledEditText. It is all working now.

Comment: @walimbeakshay i am glad that i could help, happy coding